# What do I need to change when I'm moving my wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to move my blog to a another server. I guess I need to change database details and base url.

But I am not sure. Could anyone tell me what I need to change and where I can find these files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Stuff like this is really easy to Google. For example, the official guide to the issue can be found using the terms `Moving Wordpress` or `Migrating Wordpress`. Always do a quick search first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Wordpress codex entry, ["Moving Wordpress"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) will answer all your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can read [Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), but here is the short version :

1. Edit `wp-config.php` with new params
2. Export your DB to a `.sql` file and do an exhaustive search and replace from your old url to your new one (needed for correcting the media URLs). Then import your `.sql` in your new DB.
3. In your new DB, change in `wp_options` the two fields `siteurl` and `home`

You're done !

Comment: See my answer about how using a text editor will break serialized data.

Comment: I've done many transfers and I've never had any issue with that. I don't understand, in what will this break serialized data ? Is there any checksum of these data ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing **domains** as well as servers, you need to find/replace URLs in the data by using queries in phpmyadmin. Finding/replacing with a text editor in a database dump will **break serialized data**.

Use:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.olddomain.com/','http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://www.olddomain.com/', 'http://www.newdomain.com/');
```

See [How to Move WordPress Blog to New Domain or Location  »  My Digital Life](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/10/01/how-to-move-wordpress-blog-to-new-domain-or-location/)  as well as [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)